# How to use subqueries in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables.

Table *user*:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ud_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

and *mycatch*:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mycatch` (
  `catch_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catch_name` text NOT NULL,
  `catch_details` text NOT NULL,
  `longitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `image` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`catch_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE `mycatch`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `mycatch_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

My goal is: I want to retrieve longitude and latitude from *mycatch* against given *ud_id* (from *user*) and *catch_id* (from *mycatch*) where *ud_id* = given *ud_id* and *catch_id* > given *catch_id*.

I used the query but fail to retrieve

```
SELECT ud_id=$ud_id FROM user
WHERE user_id =
(
SELECT user_id,longitude,latitude from mycatch
WHERE catch_id>'$catch_id'
)
```

The error is:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Your SQL makes no sense. Why do you select `longitude` and `latitude` if you just want `user_id` from your subquery, and why does the outer `SELECT` set a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Select m.longitude,m.latitude from user u left join mycatch m 
on u.user_id =m.user_id 
where u.ud_id=$ud_id and 
m.catch_id >$catch_id
```

Comment: i need just longitude and latitude from mycatch against given ud_id and catch_id

Comment: in fact you don't even need the join; just query the `mycatch` table and you'll be OK...

Answer (score 2):

First, try not to use subqueries at all, they're very slow in MySQL.

Second, a subquery wouldn't even help here.  This is a regular join (no, Mr Singh, not an inner join):

```
SELECT ud_id FROM user, mycatch
WHERE catch_id>'$catch_id'
AND user.user_id = mycatch.user_id
```